# Trace part of Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, discrete

Given an electron in one discrete dimension, the Hamiltonian is given by $H_{n,n'}\in Mat_{N\times N}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ acting on $l^2\left(\mathbb{C}^N\right)$ where $N$ is some integer counting the number of "internal" degrees of freedom, so that the Schreodinger equation is: $$ \sum_{n'}H_{n,n'}\psi_{n'}=E\psi_{n} $$ where $\psi_n \in \mathbb{C}^N$ is the wave-function at space-position $n$.

If we are working in some kind of nearest-neighbor approximation, then we could write the Hamiltonian as $H_{nn'}=B\delta_{n,n'+1}+B^{\ast}\delta_{n,n'-1}+B^{0}\delta_{n,n'}$ where $B^0$ is a Hermitian $N\times N$ matrix and $B$ is *any* $N\times N$ matrix.

In many articles that I'm reading, the trace part of $B$ and $B^0$ is discarded and they are assumed, from the get go, to be traceless. My question is: why? What does the trace part of these matrices signify? For example, in this article: [Mong and Shivamoggi 2011](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.2778) they show a certain correspondence, however, assuming from the start that there is no trace part for the Hamiltonian. Why is the proof still valid? Is there any reason why this trace part should be zero in realistic systems?

Comment: an hamiltonian is linked to total energy, which in turn is defined up to a constant, which could as well be the trace of the hamiltonian itself.

Comment: I can see that being true for $B^0$, which is indeed a constant, but for $B$ you actually shift the energy by different amounts for different crystal momenta (if you have translational symmetry, for instance). Then I don't see why you may simply disregard that part.